# What is the best database for this data set?

Tags: database, database-design, redis

I have an app (for a given twitter user) that gets a list of twitter users that you follow **but don't follow you back**. It does this:

- compare two lists, one from time x and time y, too see if more people followed you back or less.
- See how long it took for twitter user x to follow you back.
- See how many retweets/comments it took for user x to follow you back

The easy way I came up with is just a have a has-many belongs to relationship w/ a user and people not following you back, e.g.:

```
User table
-id

TwitterUser table
-user_id 
-timestamp
-isFollowing
```

So w/ that SQL schema I can get all the non-following back users for a given user and they can be compared by timestamp to match requirements above.

However, I was hoping that there was a better DB backend to represent this dataset than an sql database. I've been experimenting w/ redis but not sure how to pull it off.

I'm thinking maybe a document store - b/c all I want to do is take a diff of two data sets. Or more precisely: I want to diff two lists of twitter user ids.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Bruteforce approach of comparing two arrays will have a time complexity of O(N*M), where N and M are sizes of arrays. So, we should instead store them using some intelligent data structure to do this efficiently.

I've come up with the following approaches:

1. List of twitter ids' is a set because ids are unique. Redis supports
   sets and allows performing set operations like difference. Suppose
   you have 2 sets with the keys `ids_at_time_x` and `ids_at_time_y`.
   Add elements to them using `SADD`
   like this:

   ```
   SADD ids_at_time_x "15424"
   ```

   When you're ready to perform a diff execute

   ```
   SDIFF ids_at_time_x ids_at_time_y
   ```

   This will return a list of ids from `ids_at_time_x` that are NOT
   present in `ids_at_time_y`. If you want to do reverse operation,
   i.e. retrieve a list of ids that are not present in `ids_at_time_x`,
   just swap arguments:

   ```
   SDIFF ids_at_time_y ids_at_time_x
   ```

   The best thing about SDIFF is that it operates very efficiently -
   time complexity is O(N) where N is the total number of elements in
   these 2 sets. Even if you do 2 diff operations, time complexity will
   still be linear.
2. Store them as a sorted list. Redis supports sorted sets. When adding
   id you have to include a score of element (Redis will do sorting based on score) which equals to id in your
   case:

   ```
   ZADD ids_at_time_x 15424 "15424"
   ```

   When lists are ready, we retrieve both of them and compare them in
   code. Here is pseudocode:

   ```
   n = size of A
   m = size of B
   i = 0
   j = 0
   setA = [] // List of elements that present only in A
   setB = [] // List of elements that present only in B
   intersection = [] // List of elements that present in A and B

   while i < n or j < m {
     if j == m {
       setA.add(A[i])
       i = i + 1
     } else if i == n {
       setB.add(B[j])
       j = j + 1
     } else if A[i] < B[j] {
       setA.add(A[i])
       i = i + 1
     } else if B[j] < A[i] {
       setB.add(B[j])
       j = j + 1
     } else {
       intersection.add(A[i])
       i = i + 1
       j = j + 1
     }
   }
   ```

   Explanation: We use the fact that A and B are sorted. We have two indexes, both starting at zero. Compare the
   two first elements of A and B. If A[0] is less than B[0], we know
   that A[0] is present only in A so we add it to the list setA and
   increase index of A by one. If B[0] is less than A[0], we add B[0]
   to the list setB and increase index of B by one. If A[0] == B[0] we
   add A[0] to the list of intersections and increment both indexes.
   This code also works in linear time O(N) where N is total number of
   elements in both A and B.

   Note that this approach will work with any database which can return sorted list, meaning you can store it in a traditional SQL database and retrieve lists using `ORDER BY twitter_id`).

Have a look at all [Data types](http://redis.io/topics/data-types) supported by Redis and full list of their commands, they are nicely documented. Redis also have official clients available in many languages so this shouldn't be a problem.
You can still store important data in an SQL database and let Redis handle lists of ids.

Comment: Very interesting response - thank you. I didn't thinking about the growth rate analysis yet, but that is a very important consideration. I'm considering your first design, but If I wanted to associate a set of id's with a user should I just add the user ID to the key? e.g.: SADD user_a_ids_at_time_x "15424" or is that bad redis design?

Comment: @eggie5 Including user id in a key is perfectly valid. Typically, programmers use `:` as a separator, so the key holding a set might follow pattern like `user:$USERID:ids:$UNIXTIMESTAMP`, example: `user:153343:ids:1337939983`. Using a pattern similar to this, you'll be able to dynamically construct keys. [Redis' official twitter clone](http://redis.io/topics/twitter-clone) is a nice read for beginners

Comment: ok i'll take a look at the twitter clone example and to that key scheme.

Comment: Forget redis and persistance for a moment and let's just start w/ the objects in the data model. I'll go even simpler and start w/ following and followers sets (id arrays) and then use ruby (my environment) and set logic to derive the other useful sets. For example the intersection of those two sets is the set who I am following-and-following-me-back. And those who are not following me back would be the diff of following and following-and-following-me-back.

Comment: ex: (ruby)
following=twitter_client.friend_ids(user_id).ids
followers=twitter_client.follower_ids(user_id).ids
follow_and_follow_back = following & followers #ruby intersection
not_following_me_back = following - follow_and_follow_back #ruby diff
i_dont_follow_back= followers - follow_and_follow_back
Now if we think about persistance the redis sets solution is very optimal. Like you suggested:`sadd user:$USERID:following_ids:$TIMESTAMP [324,2342,..], sadd $USR....
Now to get the data I want the intersection of those two sets I can do that either on the redis level or the ruby level:SINTERSTORE

Answer (score 0):

neo4j (http://neo4j.org) is a database engine built for storing data as a graph.  I don't have any experience with actually using neo4j, but it seems like it would be a good fit.

Comment: why do you think it would be a good graph representation?

Comment: A set of Twitter users, and the relationships between them, inherently form a directed graph, where each user is a node, and each follow relationship is an edge from one node to another.

Comment: OK, but do you think a graph still applies since I'm simply taking a snapshot at time x, y, z... of a user a's friends who aren't following back?